# Is it possible to generate code in a module after downloading it?

Tags: go, code-generation, go-modules

As the title says, is it possible to generate code (with something like `//go:generate`) after a module dependency is downloaded?

Specifically, let's say there's a repo `example.com/protobuf` containing some `.proto` files and a few `.sh` scripts for generating bindings in different languages, plus a `go.mod` so it can be used as a dependency from go like so:

```
module example.com/application

go 1.18

require (
  example.com/protobuf v1.0.0
)
```

However, the generated `.go` files are not included in this repo, they have to be generated using one of the `.sh` scripts, so if you try this, you get an error like `module example.com/protobuf@latest found (v1.0.0), but does not contain package example.com/protobuf/foo`

Is there a way around this without resorting to eg. git submodules?

Comment: No, the generated code should be included in the module.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to _automatically_ run `go generate` on a module after downloading? That would be dreadful from a security standpoint (and a possible headache for keeping up the property of being cross-platform, and the requirement to have the necessary tooling installed). All-in-all, I'm with JimB on this; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56417892/720999/) is the reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible for obvious security reasons.